# How to use Yii2 Queue::EVENT_AFTER_ERROR event

Tags: yii2, queue

I'm using Yii2 Queue extension.

I want to add error handler after triggering error event in job.

This is my model:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\BaseObject;
use yii\queue\JobInterface;
use yii\queue\Queue;

class AddTransaction extends BaseObject implements JobInterface
{
    public function execute($queue)
    {
        $test = new League();
        $test->title_fa = 'تست';
        $test->title_en = 'test';
        $test->status = 1;
        $test->country_id = 3;
        $test->created = time();
        $test->save();
    }
}
```

This is my action:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    if (Yii::$app->queue->delay(5)->push(new AddTransaction())) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

Where use this code?

```
Yii::$app->queue->on(Queue::EVENT_AFTER_ERROR, function (ErrorEvent $event) {
     if ($event->job instanceof SomeJob) {
         $event->retry = ($event->attempt < 5) && ($event->error instanceof TemporaryException);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add this to queue config array:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'queue' => [
        // ...
        'on afterError' => function (ExecEvent $event) {
            if ($event->job instanceof SomeJob) {
                $event->retry = ($event->attempt < 5) && ($event->error instanceof TemporaryException);
            }
        },
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In advanced template you have bootstrap.php config file there you may subscribe to events and so on.

This is one of adopted examples from [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events#class-level-event-handlers)

```
Event::on(Queue::className(), Queue::EVENT_AFTER_ERROR, function ($event) {
    Yii::debug(get_class($event->sender) . ' is error');
});
```